# Stopping the program until response data is downloaded in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been trying to build a spider with Scrapy (Python) and have run into a problem I cannot tackle myself. 
Here is a code snippet:

```
    def parse(self, response):        
        print "one"
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
               response,
               url="url.php",
               callback=self.funkcija2,
            )
        print "three"

    def funkcija2(self, response):
        print "two"
```

This prints me one, three, and then two. As far as I understand, what happens here is it prints one, then in waits until the response is downloaded and during that prints three, and only then it executes the callback function which prints two. What I would like to do, though, is stop the program until response data is downloaded, perform callback function and only then continue with what is after the request. Is that possible?

Is my understanding of when the callback function is called correct? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the usage of yield in that case is correct, because the result of calling the `parse(self, response)` function will be a generator. As for you other question, scrapy is an asynchronous framework so if you want to make sure that something is executed after the response is downloaded, you need to put that in the callback function. In your case, that means that the statement `print "three"` should be after the `print "two"` statement in `funkcija2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I'm using `yield` is that I actually have another `FormRequest` after the statement `print "three"`, only didn't include it here. And I cannot put the second `FormRequest` in the callback function because I need it to be based on the same response as the first `FormRequest`. Is that possible?

Comment: Read this page and you will find exactly what you need: [Spiders Documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/spiders.html)

Comment: You can actually make another FormRequest in the parse function with the same response, but you cannot control which Response will be downloaded first.

Comment: Did you mean CrawlSpider? Could you explain how it could help me here then?
I realize I can make the request in the parse function, and I do not need to control which one will be downloaded first - what I need though, is for the program to stop and wait for the first response to be downloaded and the callback function to be executed before sending the second request.